# I'm trying to start an activity from a service running in background but its not working..can anyone help me out?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start an activity from a service running in background but its not working.. here's the code. the service class uses an intent to call activity class. can anyone help me out??

```
//The service class
public class ServiceTemplate extends Service
{
    // code to execute when the service is starting up 
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Accelerometer initiated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // to set a delay
        Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
        {
           @Override
           public void run()
           {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Accelerometer running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // Change state here
           }
        };

        Handler myHandler = new Handler();
        myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 5000);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, TimerAct.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

//The Activity class
public class TimerAct extends Activity
{
    static TextView timeDisplay;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.time);

        int length = 30000;

        timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        timeDisplay.setText("Time left: " + length / 1000);
    }   
}
```

Comment: First off, onStart() is deprecated, you should use onStartCommand(). Secondly, where are you starting the Service initially?

Comment: Maybe you can describe a little more of how it's not working. Do you get the toasts from your service, but your activity never starts?

Comment: @LuxuryMode I'm starting the service from another activity by using startService() method en that works fine.. but after the service starts, i'm not able to start the new activity. i get the option "Force Close"

Comment: @kabuko yeah i get the toasts if i don't call the activity. but when i write the code for calling activity using intent, then not even toasts are being called. i get the message "Force Close"

Comment: Post your stack trace from LogCat for when you see that force close...

Comment: If you're getting a force close then post the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `Service` is not a UI component, you need to start a new task. Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TimerAct.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```